# alias with if else inside in csh

Tags: if-statement, alias, csh

I want to write alias (csh) that work differently if there is more then 1 argument.

```
alias iftest 'if ($#argv > "1") \
      echo "oo" \
      else \
      echo "ii" \
      endif' \
```

But the code always print "oo"

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: >> iftest 1 2 3

while printing $#argv I get 0

Comment: Do yourself a favor and give up on `csh`. Aliases in Bourne-family shells are similarly limited but at least there are alternatives.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If I can make a recommendation, do not use C Shell any further. The shell itself has major flaws and random bugs and should be avoided to be used. Take your time and read [Top 10 Reasons not to use C Shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) and [csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). Maybe attempt to use a more stable shell such as bash or zsh or just stick to pure Posix sh.

Comment: `alias iftest '[ \`echo \!:e | wc -w\` -gt 1] && echo "oo" || echo "ii"'`